# ProtoBuf-net TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix loop

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, serialization, protobuf-net

I'm using ProtoBuf-net version 3.2.26.38424

I'm trying to Serialize and Deserialize a dictionary, so that the the deserialization will be done entry by entry of the dictionary, and not all of the dictionary at once (at once works fine).

The Serialization works fine like this:

```csharp
volatile ConcurrentDictionary<Int64, byte[]> Dic_Holdings;

private void WriteEncryptedDataFile(object dataObject, string fileFullPath, string password)
{
    DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider
    {
        Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password.Substring(0, 8)),
        IV  = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password.Substring(0, 8))
    };
    using( var fs = new FileStream(fileFullPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write) )
    {
        CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(fs, cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        foreach( KeyValuePair<Int64, byte[]> item in Dic_Holdings )
        {
            Serializer.NonGeneric.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(crStream, item, PrefixStyle.Base128, 0);
            //Serializer.NonGeneric.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(crStream, item, PrefixStyle.Base128, 0); // tried this also
        }
        crStream.Close();
    }
}
```

But the Deserialization fail.
First I tried doing the deserialization by loop, using
`Serializer.Deserialize<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<long, byte[]>>(crStream)`
But there is no stop condition I can use, so at the end of the file, I get an exception.

So now I'm using `Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix` like this:

```csharp
private object ReadEncryptedDataFile(string fileFullPath, Type objectType, string password)
{
    password = password.PadRight(8, ' ').Substring(0, 8);

    DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider
    {
        Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password),
        IV  = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password)
    };
    ConcurrentDictionary<Int64, byte[]> dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<Int64, byte[]>();
    using( var fs = new FileStream(fileFullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read) )
    {
        CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(fs, cryptic.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Type> { { 1, typeof(Int64) }, { 2, typeof(byte[]) } };
        System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<long, byte[]> item;
        while( Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(crStream, PrefixStyle.Base128, fieldNum => lookup[fieldNum], out object obj) )
        {
            item = (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<long, byte[]>)obj;
            dic.TryAdd(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
    return dic;
}
```

But the `TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix` fail at the first time, throwing:

```
**System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=Unexpected wire-type: EndGroup, expected String)
Source=protobuf-net.Core**
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Solved...
Changed the serialization to:

Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(crStream, item, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
//Serializer.NonGeneric.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(crStream, item, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1); // also works.


And the deserialization to:

while( Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(crStream,
                                                            PrefixStyle.Base128, i => typeof(KeyValuePair<Int64, byte[]>),
                                                            out object obj) )